# How can I replace a for loop with a lambda and stream in Java?

Tags: java, lambda

How can I convert the following for loop to use a Java lambda with streams?

```
List<Fruit> fruits = createFruitArrayList (); // creates a list of fruits
Fruit largeApple = null;    // holds the largest apple so far for  
for (Fruit fruit : fruits) { 
  if (fruit.getType () == “Apple”) { 
    if (largeApple == null ||
     largeApple.size () < fruit.size ()) {
      largeApple = fruit;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Improved formatting and added more descriptive words to assist with the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) to compare the two values

```
Comparator<Fruit> comp = (fruit1, fruit2) -> Integer.compare( fruit1.size(), fruit2.size());
Fruit largeApple = fruits.stream().max(comp).get();
```

Also the way you compare strings is wrong

```
if (fruit.getType () == “Apple”)
```

What you proberly want

```
if (fruit.getType().equals("Apple"))
```

For more Information on that, take a look at this question:
[How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

Danger, Will Robinson! Don't use `==` to compare strings! Use `equals()`.

That said, this code is equivalent to your loop:

```
Fruit largestApple = fruits.stream()
  .filter(f -> f.getType().equals("Apple"))
  .max(Comparator.comparing(Fruit::size))
  .orElse(null);
```

Note the use of a *method reference* (rather than a lambda) as the parameter passed to `comparing()`.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it works:

```
public void test() {
    // creates a list of fruits
    List<Fruit> fruits = Arrays.asList(
            new Fruit("Apple", 10),
            new Fruit("Apple", 14),
            new Fruit("Pear", 4));
    // Old style.
    // holds the largest apple so far
    Fruit largeApple = null;
    for (Fruit fruit : fruits) {
        if (fruit.getType().equals("Apple")) {
            if (largeApple == null
                    || largeApple.size() < fruit.size()) {
                largeApple = fruit;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Old: " + largeApple);
    // New Style.
    Optional<Fruit> max = fruits.stream()
            .filter(f -> f.type.equals("Apple"))
            .max(Comparator.comparing(f -> f.size));
    System.out.println("Lambda: " + max);

}
```

BTW: Your sample code is terrible - please post a working sample in real syntactically correct java.

Comment: Thanks. That sample code is a sample question my teacher gave us in school

Comment: @DamiAbiola - Then either your teacher doesn't know any Java or you didn't copy it properly.